# ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3 when interacting with S3 from Flink application

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink

I am trying to download some Avro files from S3 using Flink. But I am getting the below error not sure why. I have add the aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.342.jar and hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar jar file to the flink lib directory. The program runs fine when there is no s3 interaction, but gives the error messages when trying to interact with s3. What could be the issue here ?

Flink cluster version : 1.3.2

SBT dependency:-

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.11"

val flink_version = "1.3.2"
val slf4j_version = "1.7.25"
val playJson_version = "2.6.3"
val avro_version = "1.8.2"
val cassandra_version = "3.3.0"
val mongodb_version = "3.5.0"
val commons_version = "1.40"
val aws_sdk_version = "1.11.342"

val dependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flink_version,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % flink_version,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-avro" % flink_version,
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.7.4"  % Provided,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-hadoop-compatibility" % flink_version,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-cassandra" % flink_version,
  "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % mongodb_version,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % playJson_version,
  "org.apache.avro" % "avro-mapred" % "1.7.1",
  "com.paulgoldbaum" %% "scala-influxdb-client" % "0.4.3",

  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" % aws_sdk_version,
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % aws_sdk_version % Provided
) ++ Seq(
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.9.4" % Test,
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % Test,
  "com.amazonaws" % "DynamoDBLocal" % "[1.11,2.0)" % Test,
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % slf4j_version,
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % slf4j_version
)
```

Error:-

```
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.aroundReceive(JobManager.scala:125)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Creating the input splits caused an error: com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.<init>(ExecutionJobVertex.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.attachJobGraph(ExecutionGraph.java:780)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(ExecutionGraphBuilder.java:166)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:1315)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1880)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2298)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.getHadoopWrapperClassNameForFileSystem(HadoopFileSystem.java:486)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getHadoopWrapperClassNameForFileSystem(FileSystem.java:437)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:339)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:293)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat.createInputSplits(FileInputFormat.java:472)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat.createInputSplits(FileInputFormat.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.<init>(ExecutionJobVertex.java:233)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: Your application jar/package which you are running doesn't seem to have added aws dependency jar. As per dependency list you have added aws core as "provided", which stops it from getting added as part of application package

Comment: but I have added those 2 libraries inside the lib folder of the cluster, do you think we still need to add in sbt dependencies also ?

Comment: I am not sure specific setup you have... but its clear from the error , that it is unable to find this jar. I would suggest to check, how other dependency are added in your application. also try to remove the "provided " from aws core dependency